# R select and modify columns by condition in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a big data frame with interest rates structured as follows

```
a <- "a"
b <- 2015
c <- as.vector(c(-0.3, -0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5))

df <- data.frame(a,b,t(c))
colnames(df) <- c("Type", "Year", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5")
```

Now I want substract 1 from interest rates in columns X1 - X5 only if the figure is > 0

I tried

```
df[1,df[3:7]>0] <- df[1,df[3:7]>0] - 1
```

which results in

```
 X1   X2   X3
-1.3 -1.1 -0.8
```

I also saw, that

```
df[3:7]>0
```

results in:

```
X1    X2   X3   X4   X5
FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I see that the columns obtained by the condition are (3,4,5), while I would need (5,6,7).

Also, is there an easy way to copy the row, so that there is the original and the modified row?

I am working with R only since some days and would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Bit of a hack but the quickest way would be to use the fact that logicals are evaluated at F = 0, T = 1 when added/subtracted etc from a numerical.
`df[,3:7] - (df[,3:7] > 0)` does what you want. Otherwise I would use an `ifelse()` statement.

Comment: I defaulted to an ifelse() statement: `df[1, 3:7] <- sapply(df[1, 3:7], function(x) ifelse(x > 0, x-1, x))`.  But bmrn's version is cleaner

Comment: Thanks both of you. Both ways work perfect, although I like the ifelse() way better, I will keep in mind the nice "hack" of bmrn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mutate_at`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) from `dplyr` package and [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/ifelse)

```
    library(tidyverse)
    df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(X1:X5), 
                     .funs = funs(ifelse(. > 0, . - 1, .)))

      Type Year   X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
    1    a 2015 -0.3 -0.1 -0.8 -0.7 -0.5
```

Edit: more generic

```
    df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("X")), 
                     .funs = funs(ifelse(. > 0, . - 1, .)))

    df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("X")), 
                     .funs = funs(ifelse(. > 0, . - 1, .)))
```